# Laravel simple query is taking more than 30 seconds on server

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel,Angular,Nginx stack deployed on a server with a really good configuration.

Laravel apis on localhost are really fast but on server some days a simple select query of 10 ids return 504 while same api returns the answer in 200ms on localhost, any idea where should i check or what should i do ?

Optimizing queries will help the speed and i tryed those ways but i feel there's a overhead time delaying api calls on server some days regardless of a simple select query or a complex query.

Comment: It seems this has less to do with programming, more with benchmarking the server environment. Maybe try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: Thanks, i thought it might be a problem with laravel configuration.

Comment: That could still be the case but based on your description there is not much to guess what the problem might be. You should post configuration files as well to SuperUser IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking everything on Laravel and Mysql and server i found out that the error was being caused by a large associative entity with no index declared for it in Mysql.